# Can Turbopack be used outside NextJs?

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel, turbopack

Since it's apparently very fast, It would be nice if it could be used outside for multiple projects like Vite. Couldn't find much information about it on their website https://turbo.build/pack

Went to https://github.com/vercel/turbo but couldn't find much info there either.

Comment: Not currently. It's only useable with Next.js for now, but there are plans to make it standalone.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing myself, I expect it may be a while because it's still in such an early stage of development.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, as outlined here: https://turbo.build/pack/docs#quickstart.

> As of today, Turbopack can be used in Next.js v13. In the future we will be releasing a standalone CLI, plugin API, and support for other frameworks such as Svelte and Vue.